# How to get JSON Object by variable?

Tags: node.js, json, fs

My json code:

```
var jsontest = {
    "testlang": "no no testlang dziala lol"
}
```

i want get "testlang" by variable, eg:

```
var variabletest = "testlang";
jsontest.variabletest
```

can anyone help plz?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the below would work

```
const jsontest = {
    "testlang": "no no testlang dziala lol"
}
const variabletest = "testlang";
console.log(jsontest[variabletest])
```